# Query data within a range that are also within another range

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

What I want is fairly simple but I'm wondering whats the best way of writing the query.

I have a list of businesses for example, I have a log of purchases.

I need to show returning businesses based on purchases.

Which is show me all businesses that have purchased in the last 30 days who also purchased prior to 30 days ago.

Comment: Do you mind posting sample data and the desired result?

Comment: the desired result is just a count of businesses. Like 1000. Its the number of returning businesses purchasing.

Comment: What is your SQL Server version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `SELF JOIN`:

Table **Log**

`business_id` `purchase_date` ...

```
SELECT COUNT (DISTINCT l1.business_id)
FROM Log l1
JOIN Log l2 ON l1.business_id = l2.business_id 
     AND l1.purchase_date <  DATEADD(day, -30, GETDATE())
     AND l2.purchase_date >= DATEADD(day, -30, GETDATE())
```

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/a0294/3)

Comment: I dont see that working. Surely if purchase_date has to be both less than and greater than a date it will return nothing.

Comment: Not for the same record.

Answer (score 1):

These are 2 approaches you could take -

`intersect`

```
select business_id
  from purchases
 where purchase_date >= dateadd(day, -30, getdate())
intersect
select business_id
  from purchases
 where purchase_date < dateadd(day, -30, getdate())
```

or an `exists` subquery

```
select distinct business_id
  from purchases x
 where purchase_date >= dateadd(day, -30, getdate())
   and exists (select 1
          from purchases y
         where y.purchase_date < dateadd(day, -30, getdate())
           and y.business_id = x.business_id)
```